# Apache Shiro, @RequiresRoles, 401 error code

Tags: java, apache, shiro, jaas

I have marked my `REST` method with `@RequiresRoles("role")` annotation and i do expect `401`, `403` error code to be returned(when the subject doesn't have the role specified or isn't authenticated),

but `org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthorizedException` is wrapped in `javax.servlet.ServletException:` Filtered request failed `500` error code is returned instead.

**How to configure error codes to be returned depending on exception?**

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping into `ServletException` is OK according to JAX-RS specification.

It's up to an exception mapping provider to map `org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthorizedException` to a response with the proper status. You should add one into your implementation.

I would recommend to map `org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthorizedException` to a response with `Response.Status.FORBIDDEN`.